# How to check why MySQL is denying incoming requests

Tags: mysql

I have a remote MySQL database that I am trying to connect to via my webserver.

The error I get when trying to connect via `mysqli` is

```
Connection refused 2002
```

I have invoked this command for remote connections:

```
grant all on db.* to '<user>'@'<hostname>' identified by '<password>';
```

I'm hoping I can find a more *verbose* description from my MySQL server in some log file. The question is **which one** would be appropriate?

Other questions suggest `/var/log/mysql/error.log` but I don't have any output in that file at all. I am not running a firewall of any kind currently. Possibly my `apache config` is getting in the way, but I am not sure how to check this and I presume if that was the case, I wouldn't get the `2002 error`, but instead, some other, apache-flavoured error message.

**Which debug logs should I be looking at?**

Here is the php and mysql code:

```
//define DB variables
define("DB_HOST", "45.77.xx.xxx");
define("DB_NAME", "login");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "Correct_Password");

$this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

echo mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;

echo $this->db_connection->connect_errno;
```

Output:

`$this->db_connection->connect_errno` is set to `2002` and
`mysqli_connect_error()` is set to`Connection refused`

Comment: Apache config doesn't affect the connection between PHP and MySQL. Can you please show the line of code where you use mysqli to connect to MySQL? Like `mysqli_connect(...)` or `new mysqli(...)`. Obscure the password of course. But it would help to know the values you use for hostname, port, and socket.

Comment: might be a stupid question but are you trying to connect to a remote server or your localhost?

Answer (score 1):

Granting access to tables or databases in mysql is actually associated to a user connecting from a given host, so when you do
`grant all on db.* to '<user>'@'<hostname>'` you are granting access to the user when they are connecting from "hostname" and that may be your problem.
Make sure the host you are connecting from is the same as you granted the privileges, or if you need to open up the access to other hosts on the same domain do `grant all on db.* to <user>'@'%.domain.name'...`
Check your grants with `show grants for username;`, or `select user,host from mysql.user;`.
Mysql error.log file usually just logs errors from mysql startup.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to swap the host address (45.77.xx.xxx) with your host_name?

When I had the same issue (although, mine was on localhost), I changed the host IP to from 127.0.0.1 and it worked. You may want to tit to your hostname instead of the IP address.

Comment: The database is not on localhost - it's a remote database. There is no URL hostname